# Finding path through 2D array with sum closest to given number

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I want to find the path through a 2D array of integers (no negatives, size N*N) where the sum of all the passed numbers is closest to a given number. Starting from the top left, in each step navigating through the array you can move only down or to the right. The destination is the bottom right corner of the array.

Example:

```
field = [
  [0,5,1],
  [1,3,5]
  [2,1,1]
]

n = 5

solution(field, n) => 0
// down, down, right, right

solution(field, 7) => 1
```

If no solution is found, that yields a positive number, `-1` is returned.

My inefficient solution:

```
def solution(n, field)
  res​ ​=​ ​closest(n,​ ​field)
  if​ ​res​ ​<​ ​0:
    return​ ​-1
  ​return​ ​res

def closest(n, field)
  best = n - field[0][0]
  if len(field) > 1:
    "Remove upper most row and call recursively"
    tmp = solution(n - field[0][0], field[1:])
    if tmp >= 0:
  ​    best = tmp
  if len(field[0]) > 1:
    "Remove left most column and call recursively"
    tmp = solution(n - field[0][0], [(x[0:0] + x[1:]) for x in field])
    if tmp < best:
      best = tmp
  return best
```

This works for a small field, but is highly inefficient.
For a field with 20 columns and 20 rows, it takes ages to find a solution.

Is there a more efficient way, to solve this problem. (i.e. A few seconds for a 20*20)
(Code does not have to be in python

Comment: does the field variable need to be a list of lists? or it could be tuples?

Comment: Are you sure this works because `def solution(n, field)`
  `res​ ​=​ ​solution(n,​ ​field)` would lead to an infinite recursion as neither of `n` or `field` is getting modified between recursive calls...

Comment: I changed the recursive call to clostest()

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If so ... accept it please as the solution! Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming or memoization to solve this efficiently. Firstly, the recursive function is formulated like this:

```
C(x, y, n) =   -1 if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= n or y >= n or n < 0 (1)
             | field[x][y] if x = n - 1 and y = n - 1 and n >= 0 (2)
             | -1 if FromUp = -1 and FromLeft = -1 (3)
             | field[x][y] + Max(FromUp, FromLeft) (4)
where C(x, y, n) is the length of the path closest to n ending at x and y
      FromLeft = C(x - 1, y, n - field[x][y])
      FromUp = C(x, y - 1, n - field[x][y])
```

There are 2 base cases (1) and (2), (1) means invalid row or column or n. (2) means you already reach the bottom right cell with valid n. For a particular x, y and n, you can come from either the upper cell or the cell to the left. Therefore (3) is the failed recursive case and (4) calculates the correct length for C(x, y, n) if 1 of the recursive case succeed.

If you want to use dynamic programming, you can build a 3D table and fill it with 3 nested for loops. If you want to use memoization, just code up the above recursive function; but every time you return something, record it in a 3D table and try to use the results from the table first in the function before other steps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
F = [[0,5,1],
    [1,3,5],
    [2,1,1]]

N = 3

SUM = [[0 for x in range(N)] for y in range(N)]

n = 7

def solution(row, col):
    if row==N or col==N :
        return 10**10;
    if row==N-1 and col==N-1:
        return F[row][col]

    if(SUM[row][col]):
        return SUM[row][col]

    A =  solution(row+1, col) + F[row][col]
    B =  solution(row, col+1) + F[row][col]
    if(abs(n-A)<=abs(n-B)):
        SUM[row][col] = A
    else:
        SUM[row][col] = B

    return SUM[row][col]


def RES(n):
    res = solution(0,0)
    if(res<0):
        return -1
    else:
        return abs(res-n)


print RES(n)
```